# How to comment stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, comments

I am trying to comment a stored procedure using MySQL workbench.
I tried with the following syntax -

```
/**
Hai
*/
```

and

```
-- hai
```

These two will execute perfectly but changes never gets updated to stored procedure, while opening stored procedure it does not show any changes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should place your comments inside the procedure **body**, i.e., what's between `BEGIN` and `END`. The rest of the code are instructions to create the procedure and are lost once you run them.

Comment syntax is as usual:

- `/* ... */`
- `--<space>`

MySQL Workbench conveniently warns about this:

[image]

Comment: That <space> is a huge gotcha. Devs don't need that, or the generic "there's some sort of syntax error somewhere near something in your code".

Answer (score 21):

MySQL has a comment feature. Official manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html).

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name()
COMMENT 'this is my comment'
BEGIN
/*here comes my voodoo*/
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This way you also save the comment in the database, not just in your source code.